# How to Create a Custom Text Area (Long) Attribute in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to create a custom attribute in Salesforce Marketing Cloud that is of type `Text Area (Long)`, similar to how we can create custom attributes in Salesforce. However, I am unable to find the option for a "Long" text area in SFMC.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to create a custom attribute of this type in SFMC?

Answer (score 0):

In Email Studio, leaving the field length blank for a text attribute in a Data Extension will set it to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. Note that this does not work in Contact Builder.